# Is it possible to update the WP7 lock screen in code?

Tags: mobile, windows-phone-7

Is it possible to update the WP7 lock screen in code? I want to write an application that allows me to download new background images. I would like to be able to update the lock screen (background
) image directly from this application.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not possible to change anything on the lock screen from a 3rd party application currently.